# VB.NET DataGridView copy to clipboard

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview, formatting, clipboard

I'm trying to copy the content of a DataGridView into clipboard, but I want to copy only text without any information regarding formatting. This request is because my goal is to paste data from DGV to Excel, but only text without any other information like wrap-text, etc...

There is a way to copy only text of the cells?

Thank you.

Comment: Clip board probably is not the way to go. Search for DataGridView to Excel. I think there is a great deal of info on this.

Comment: Thank you Mary for your trick, but I'm writing a RemoteApp that runs in a Terminal Server. If I choose your way, I need Excel in the Terminal Server, and I will send data to this instance of Excel. Instead of this, I need to export data to user's local copy of Excel. Do you think there is a way to do this work?

Comment: What have you tried (i.e.: show us your code)?  Demonstrate that you have read the documentation for the relevant methods used to get the information on the clipboard.  If you had read the documentation, I would hope that you would know how to proceed, but if not what did you not comprehend?

Comment: Hi TnTinMn. Initially I tried to use the CTRL+C shortcut to copy data to the clipboard, but with data I copied formatting info too. So I tried to implement a new method for copying data. I used the GetClipboardContent() method of DGV, but this method copies formatting information also. Lastly I tried to add the GetText method and now I can copy only text without formatting info. I think I can use this way. Thank you for your help!